# How to read an XML file from my WCF application bin folder

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am referencing a dll in my WCF project and this dll reads a .xml file using below code.

```
 var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), Constants.Configuration.FileConstants.AEC_XML_FILE);
```

When I am deploying this WCF in IIS. It searches .xml file in below path -

```
"C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Corporation\Internet Information Services\7.5.7600.16385\Calculation.xml"
```

It should read .xml from bin folder of WCF but it is searching .xml from above path. What could be the  reason?

Comment: I wonder how IIS bootstraps your WCF app? Might this bootstrapper be the "entry" assembly? How about `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` instead?

Answer (score 2):

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` will not give the path to your DLL (which isn't the entry point).

You can get the root folder for your Service with [HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx).